# Python: Recursively create a list of lists of ints with conditions

Tags: python, recursion

I want to create all possible distributions of n items. This refers to the commonly known pigeonhole principle.

The following values are the result of Microsoft Excel:

```
get_distributions(list, number_of_items_to_distribute)
get_distributions([], 1) = [[1]]
get_distributions([], 2) = [[1, 1], [2]]
get_distributions([], 3) = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3]]
get_distributions([], 4) = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4]]
```

I already have some code, but there are some issues with deleting the temporary lists.

```
all_distributions = []

def get_distributions(distribution, items):

    print('call with distribution = ' + str(distribution) + ', items = ' + str(items))
    print('---------------')

    # base case
    if items == 0:
        all_distributions.append(distribution)
        print('end: ' + str(distribution))
        distribution.clear()
        return []

    # recursion
    else:
        for i in range(1, items + 1):
            distribution.append(i)
            get_distributions(distribution, items - i)
```

With this I get good results printed out after "end: ", but some values like [1, 2] (calling with n = 3) are missing. Additionally to this the values are not appended to my all_distributions.

I'm interested in the way I tried to solve this problem. Is this a good approach or am I absolutely wrong?

Comment: what does clear method?, list hasn't this attribute

Comment: @PasqualGuerrero: The `clear` method exists in Python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that the list `all_distributions` ends up containing many references to the same input list `distribution`. When you call `all_distributions.append(distribution)`, the list `distribution` is not copied into the list `all_distributions`, but merely a reference to the list is appended. You can fix this by explicitly inserting a copy: `all_distributions.append(list(distribution))`

A minimal fix to your code is to insert copies, remove `distribution.clear()` in the base case, and adding `distribution.pop()` after the recursive call:

```
all_distributions = []

def get_distributions(distribution, items):
    if items == 0:
        all_distributions.append(list(distribution))
    else:
        for i in range(1, items + 1):
            distribution.append(i)
            get_distributions(distribution, items - i)
            distribution.pop()

get_distributions([], 3)
print(all_distributions)
```

Outputs: `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3]]`

---

A better way is to avoid using `distribution.append`, and instead using the plus operator on lists, like so:

```
def get_distributions(distribution, items):
    if items == 0:
        all_distributions.append(distribution)
    else:
        for i in range(1, items + 1):
            d = distribution + [i]
            get_distributions(d, items - i)
```

The plus operator on lists creates a new list by concatenating the two given lists. In this case, we are concatenating a single element `i` on the right side of `distribution` to get a new copy containing the elements in `distribution` followed by `i`.

---

Another improvement is to avoid the global variable `all_distributions`, and instead return the list of distributions:

```
def get_distributions(distribution, items):
    if items == 0:
        return [distribution]
    else:
        all_distributions = []
        for i in range(1, items + 1):
            d = distribution + [i]
            all_distributions += get_distributions(d, items - i)
        return all_distributions

print(get_distributions([], 4))
```

Outputs: `[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4]]`

Comment: The `list(distribution)` may still parse distribution allocation to `all_distributions` so that 'all_distribtuions` is altered as `distribution` is.
The best way would be to use `deepcopy`.
`from copy import deepcopy as dc`
then change `list(distribution)` to `dc(distribution)`

Comment: @GabrielS.Gusmão: `deepcopy` is overkill in this situation, as there is no reason the elements in `distribution` should recursively be copied; using `copy.copy` is sufficient. Of course, in this case, `distribution` contains integers, so it does not matter, but you should always think before choosing `copy` or `deepcopy`.

Comment: You're right. That is true indeed. But `list` should not be used anyways. Change it so I can upvote the answer.